# Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc() in __libc_freeres()

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm compiling the code with -g flag and -O0. Please see valgrind output below.

I only want to know if I  can I see what is invalid freed? I only see this:

```
==2566== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==2566==    at 0x4A21244: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:468)
==2566==    by 0x500FB7A: free_mem (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
==2566==    by 0x500F781: __libc_freeres (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
==2566==    by 0x491C719: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:62)
==2566==    by 0x4F4E6F4: exit (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
==2566==    by 0x4F3930A: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.4.so)
==2566==  Address 0x403ef10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2566==
==2566==
==2566== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2566==     in use at exit: 2,416,506 bytes in 1,844 blocks
==2566==   total heap usage: 62,683 allocs, 60,840 frees, 2,957,293 bytes allocated
==2566==
==2566== Searching for pointers to 1,844 not-freed blocks
==2566== Checked 5,445,056 bytes
```

The code:

```
int HoleInstrumentenDiffListeDB(GTree *tree)
{

  OCI_Connection* cn;
  OCI_Statement* st;
  OCI_Resultset* rs;
  if (!OCI_Initialize(err_handler, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
  char query[500];
  query[0] ='\0';
  cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate( "db", "u",  "p", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
  st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);
  strcat(query, "SELECT ...");

  OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, query);
  rs = OCI_GetResultset(st);
  int i = 1;
  int j = 0;
  char *symbolp;
  while (OCI_FetchNext(rs)){


    const char * symbolp = OCI_GetString(rs,2);
    switch ( * OCI_GetString(rs,3))
    {
      case 'N':
        insertQot(tree, symbolp, OCI_GetInt(rs, 1) );
        printf("new \n");
        break;
      case 'U':
        insertQot(tree, symbolp, OCI_GetInt(rs, 1) );
        printf("upd \n");
        break;
      case 'D':
        deleteQot(tree, symbolp);
        printf("del \n");
        break;
     }
  }
  OCI_Cleanup();
  return 1;
}

int main ()
{

  GTree* t = g_tree_new_full((GCompareDataFunc)g_ascii_strcasecmp,NULL,g_free,g_free);
  HoleInstrumentenListe(t);
  HoleInstrumentenDiffListeDB(t);
  g_tree_destroy (t);
}
```

Comment: We need to see code. You can have it dump debug information and you can analyze with gdb. Otherwise, we need to see code. A minimal example that shows the problem, not 100 lines.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Please again, strip out any extraneous information that does not help in reproducing the problem. There is a lot of fluff here. We will have no idea how to help you.

Comment: Try to add `--run-libc-freeres=no` parameter to `valgrind` as described in http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.rareopts .

Comment: Are the Valgrind error logs shown the only error message given by Valgrind during a single run of the program?

Comment: @alk : there are many errors(but not mostly from ocilib)

Comment: So start fixing the bugs from top to bottom.

Comment: Thank you @timrau, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be freeing `line` inside the `while ()` loop, not at the end of the `for ()` loop. I believe `getline()` will only allocate memory if the first parameter is *NULL, so you are in effect using the buffer allocated by the very first call over and over again.

But it's been a long while since I wrote much C!

Comment: He's reusing the buffer, but that shouldn't be a problem. `getline()` will call `realloc()` on the buffer if there isn't enough space on it for the current line, and in either case, the buffer address and its size are always updated on each call.

Comment: Right you are! The problem would only arise if `getline()` failed to recognise the buffer as being `malloc()`-allocated.